# Entity Framework Core get relation from database

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Perhaps I have set up my models incorrectly, or I'm expecting EF to do more work than it actually does, but...

I have a User model and a UserRole model. There is a 1 to 1 relation between User and UserRole. When I log in, the User's UserRole is null but the UserRoleId is not null. I have since set up the login function to manually get the UserRole that matches the UserRoleId, but shouldn't that relation be made implicitly?

AuthController.cs

```
public class AuthController : Controller
{
    private readonly IAuthRepository _repo;
    private readonly IConfiguration _config;
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;

    public AuthController(IAuthRepository repo, IConfiguration config, IMapper mapper)
    {
        _mapper = mapper;
        _config = config;
        _repo = repo;
    }

   [HttpPost("login")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromBody] UserForLoginDto userForLoginDto)
    {
        var userFromRepo = await _repo.Login(userForLoginDto.Username.ToLower(), userForLoginDto.Password);

       //<!<!<! userFromRepo has a NULL UserRole property !>!>!>

        if (userFromRepo == null)
            return Unauthorized();

        // generate token...

        var user = _mapper.Map<UserForListDto>(userFromRepo);
        return Ok(new {tokenString, user}
    }
```

Models\User.cs

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Username { get; set; }

    public int? UserRoleId { get; set; }
    public UserRole UserRole { get; set; }

    //other user attributes
}
```

Models\UserRole.cs

```
public class UserRole
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Role { get; set; }
}
```

Data\AuthRepository.cs

```
public class AuthRepository : IAuthRepository
{
    private readonly DataContext _context;

    public AuthRepository(DataContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public async Task<User> Login(string username, string password)
    {
        var user = await _context.Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Username == username);

        if (user == null)
            return null;

        if (!VerifyPasswordHash(password, user.PasswordHash, user.PasswordSalt))
            return null;

        //this is how I'm currently linking the User to it's UserRole
        user.UserRole = await _context.UserRoles.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == user.UserRoleId);

        // auth successful
        return user;
    }
```

Data\DataContext.cs

```
public class DataContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<UserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }

    //I do not have an explicit relation between Users and UserRoles in OnModelCreating
}
```

Comment: See [Loading Related Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data). Probably [Eager Loading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#eager-loading), e.g. `var user = await _context.Users.Include(u => u.UserRole).FirstOrDefaultAsync(...);`

Comment: Shouldn't `UserRole` have a ForeignKey attribute, i.e. `[ForeignKey(nameof(UserRoleId))]`? Otherwise how is EF to know they are related?

Comment: @stuartd The names match EF Core conventions, so no.

Comment: @IvanStoev ah ok thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @IvanStoev, your solution worked! Thanks!
What I did was: (in Login function) `var user = await _context.Users.Include(u => u.UserRole).FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Username == username);`

Comment: Also, I didn't see your edit before writing all of that out. haha

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to specify the foreign key like this:

```
public class User
{
   public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Username { get; set; }

    public int? UserRoleId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserRoleId")]
    public UserRole UserRole { get; set; }

    //other user attributes
}
```

EF can do this automatically, but you must add another property to the `UserRole` class.

```
public List<User> Users { get; set; }
```

More information about this on the EF docs site: [EF-Core Data Annotations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships#data-annotation)

Comment: None of these is required. And also won't solve loading related data issue.

Comment: Thanks @IvanStoev, but I think they are because it doesn't meet the conventions common pattern `The most common pattern for relationships is to have navigation properties defined on both ends of the relationship and a foreign key property defined in the dependent entity class.`